# Windows + E slow open of explorer window

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Recently I stumbled upon the following issue on Windows 7 x64.

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, it takes 3 seconds for the window to appear. However, when I double-click on my computer icon, the Explorer window appears instantly. Other <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> shortcuts work instantly, too.

Do you have any ideas what could've happened? I do not recall installing any applications recently.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, try using Win+E after [starting Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem

In my case the problem was the machine was always loaded with some background process which was enabled in my startrup.

I removed unwanted startup applcations from the start-up (Run -> msconfig) and the the problem was not completely resolved but I could see some difference in response time.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you expand upon this a bit? Some screenshots would be useful.